# ASP.NET MVC 5 not showing intellisense or code colour

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have what seems to be an intermittent problem with my copy of visual studio 2012 where c# razor code is not showing intellisense or code colours. I have searched and have seen a few people with what sounds like the same issue however none of the fixes provided seem to solve my issue. I have checked my web config and packages files to ensure the correct version of MVC is present (5.2) and i still cannot resolve this issue. Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Does it happen on all projects, or just that one?

Comment: This is happening on all projects in the solution

Comment: Sorry... I meant does it happen on all *solutions*?

Comment: Though i may like to add that it has not always being like this and i dont recall installing any updates which should alter anything

Comment: Oh, it does yes. if i create a new solution it is still not working, leading me to think i need to make a change to my copy of visual studio?

Comment: Indeed. When my intellisense broke I had to uninstall everything and reinstall it fresh (which takes hours) :( I have been running VS2013 Pro release 3 without  problems.

Comment: Ah right. I initially started using 2013 and never had any issues however due to an expired licence i had to switch to 2012 again. Ill see if i can get 2013 back. Thank you very much for your assistance.